# Accidentally deleted folder of 3000 files in SVN trunk

Tags: svn, svn-merge

we currently are using SVN and a developer accidentally deleted a folder of 3000 files and then added them back in fresh and committed. Then that branch was reintegrated into trunk. So now our SVN trunk has a history that shows a folder being deleted then 3000 files being added back.

Any idea how we can revert trunk back to the revision prior to the merge? My fear is if we do a revert that wont solve the problem because when we try and synchronize one branch from trunk it will replay all the checkins and delete the folder and then recreate, essentially blowing all the files in that branch.

Comment: Did they really "add them back in fresh" or did they use SVN commands to undo the deletion? I.e., is it a "delete" followed by an "add", or did you reverse-merge the delete?

Comment: If it was a reverse merge, you should be fine. If not, you need to reverse merge the trunk into itself to the revision before the files were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question it looks like the reverse merge actually fixed the problem.

i simply did a reverse merge svn -r10:2  and that fixed it.